# WPF - PropertyChanged EventHandler not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm having a problem with subscribing to PropertyChangedEventHandler event of a property on a bound instance of my class.

Here is the setup:

XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyObservableClassInstance.BooleanProperty}"/>
```

DataContext class property:

```
public MyObservableClass MyObservableClassInstance 
{
    get { return _myClassInstance; }
    set
    {
        _myClassInstance= value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyObservableClassInstance"));
    }
}
```

the initialisation and subscription to PropertyChanged event (this subscribed method is never reached):

```
MyObservableClassInstance = new MyObservableClass();
MyObservableClassInstance.PropertyChanged += OnMyObservableClassPropertyChanged; // <--- This method is never hit
```

my observable class: (the BooleanProperty is working normally with the the XAML checkbox binding)

```
public class MyObservableClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _mybool = false;
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool BooleanProperty
    {
        get { return _mybool; }
        set
        {
            _mybool = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BooleanProperty")); // <--- This is reached normally on checking/unchecking the checkbox
        }
    }
}
```

So why is my OnMyObservableClassPropertyChanged method never reached upon Invoking the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Can you please post your whole code? I think the point in time is important WHEN you instantiate "MyObservableClassInstance". Maybe this instance is not set when the binding is about to be analyzed.

Comment: And furthermore you need a TwoWayBinding in your XAML code ;)

Comment: @Sandman The IsChecked property binds TwoWay by default.

Comment: @Sandman I was just about to comment that this is the only time the instance is instantiated (and code is same except for different names) when I remembered that there is another part where saved data from DB is loaded in.. and sure enough the instance was being overwritten there. Sorry, rookie mistake, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach (and detach) the handler method to the PropertyChanged event whenever the MyObservableClass property value changes.

```
public MyObservableClass MyObservableClassInstance 
{
    get { return _myClassInstance; }
    set
    {
        if (_myClassInstance != null)
        {
            _myClassInstance.PropertyChanged -= OnMyObservableClassPropertyChanged;
        }

        _myClassInstance = value;

        if (_myClassInstance != null)
        {
            _myClassInstance.PropertyChanged += OnMyObservableClassPropertyChanged;
        }

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyObservableClassInstance)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a good solution to safeguard against an instance changing - which in my case was what was going on. (as commented above: there was another part where saved data from DB is loaded in and the instance was being overwritten there.) Thanks for the help! :)